# Setting up Apache2 VirtualHost to run multiple sites locally Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: server, apache2, localhost, hosting

I have had a site I was working on running in /var/www/html for a while. I'm starting a new project and would like to run another site locally.

After some googling, I was checking out this previous question: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1423044

I created a folder in `/var/www` called `my-site` and just cloned the git repo I will be using in there for the time being.

Then I added a file called `my-site.com.conf` to `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled`. Here's what it looks like:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName www.my-site.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/my-site/
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
</Directory>
<Directory /var/www/my-site/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>

ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
<Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log

# Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
# alert, emerg.
LogLevel warn

CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined

Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
<Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
    Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
</Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

I added the following to `/etc/hosts`:

```
127.0.0.1       www.my-site.com
```

I also ran the following command within `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled`:

```
ln -sf /etc/apache2/sites-available/my-site.com /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/my-site.com
```

The problem is that when I go in my browser to `my-site.com`, I am redirected to the old site that I had running on localhost before. My old site doesn't allow a user to go anywhere until they have logged in, and it seems like I am consistently being redirected to the login page.

How do I access my new site and set up an environment where I can work on both of these projects?

Let me know if I need to provide more information.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The content of your configuration file looks good. The problem is the filename - `my-site.com`. The configuration file must end with `.conf`, otherwise it wouldn't be included in the Apache's configuration by the directive `IncludeOptional sites-enabled/*.conf` in the main conf. file `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`. So:

```bsh
# remove the previously created symbolic link
sudo rm /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/my-site.com

# rename the configuration file
sudo mv /etc/apache2/sites-available/my-site.com{,.conf}

# enable the configuration file (create the symlink); use 'a2dissite' to disable
sudo a2ensite my-site.com.conf

# restart Apache2:
sudo systemctl restart apache2.service
```

Don't forget to flush your browser's cache and try to access your site.